# Function that receives a float, and return an int or a float in C

Tags: c, function

I was wondering if it is possible to make a function in C, that receives a float. If it has only zero after the "." then that float is converted to an int, and returns the int to the main, otherwise, it will just stay as a float and return to the main.

Comment: No, return types can not depend on values. How would the code calling the function know whether the bits returned represent an `int` or a `float`? What you can do is return a `struct` that contains a `union` and a flag that indicates which field of the `union` to use, though that can get messy and less efficient if you're not careful.

Comment: You can truncate the binary bicimals, but not decimals.

Comment: A function can only return one value of a single type, but you can use parameters of pointer types to allow it to access other objects. For example, you could pass the float value and a pointer to an `int` to the function and make the function return a value that indicates whether it set the `int`.